# How to make the text area occupy entire browser width in Bootsrap-vue while using components

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, vue.js, bootstrap-4, vue-component, bootstrap-vue

I am trying to use the first example of input groups using components from Bootstrap-Vue [website](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/input-group/#input-groups)

My Code is as below :

```
 <div>
        <b-input-group prepend="Search" class="mt-3">

             <!-- inputbox is a child component -->
                <inputBox></inputBox>

                    <b-input-group-append>
                        <b-button variant="outline-success">Button</b-button>
                        <b-button variant="info">Button</b-button>
                    </b-input-group-append>
          </b-input-group>
  </div>
```

My inputBox component code is as below:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <b-form-input></b-form-input>
</div>
</template>
```

When using the above code , my input box looks like this

[image]

instead of looking like below

[image]

How, can I make it occupy the entire width?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you are wrapping `b-form-input` with a `div`. Anyhow, if you are sure that you need to bring `b-form-input` into another component then add this style to root `div` tag:

```
<template>
  <div style="flex: 1 1 0%">
    <b-form-input></b-form-input>
  </div>
</template>
```

IF there are no items other than `b-form-input` then why not place `b-form-input` as root element without `div` wrapper:

```
<template>
  <b-form-input></b-form-input>
</template>
```

Comment: Thank you, it works both the way, I had tried without div earlier but it didn't work means I had made some mistake at that time.